# Trying to boot RPi 3 faster

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot

I don't post questions on forums often, so forgive my ignorance. I'm using a RPi 3 running Raspbian to view media on the Plex website using Chromium. Currently, my Pi takes about 70 seconds to boot, run my script to open Chromium, and navigate to the Plex website. I'm trying to get that down to under 30 seconds. Unfortunately, I am a noob when it comes to RPis. What can I disable to make this process faster?

I know I could simply use Minibian, but I am trying to become more familiar with Raspbian for a school project. Should I use Buildroot? Should I use systemd? Would `systemd-analyze blame` be helpful to find what to disable or am I likely to just break my Pi disabling stuff? Should I make a custom kernel? What would be most effective for increasing boot speed (into Chromium)?

I appreciate your help. Sorry again if this is the wrong place to start this thread or I have asked the question wrong.

Comment: A Pi3 should boot in <30 sec. `systemd-analyze critical-chain` will give more information about your boot, as will looking at output of `dmesg`. Other than that you have provided no information about configuration, why you think boot takes too long, and asked to many and too vague questions.

Comment: Follow through on what @Milliways suggest and append that data to your question - then it may be reasonable to reopen this...!

Comment: While I enjoy being talked to like I'm an idiot (@Milliways), I found what I needed elsewhere, so you can just delete this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the Pi behave normally after it boots up, or is it sluggish in general?

**SD Card**

What class is it?  I wouldn't run anything below Class 4. Also the logs might reveal any issues due to filesystem corruption

**Power Supply:**

Check the supply and cable. I've seen weird things happen to Pis due to a bad power supply. According to the Raspberry Pi documentation:

> You can check your power supply by measuring the voltage between TP1
> and TP2 on the Raspberry Pi; if this drops below 4.75V when doing
> complex tasks then it is most likely unsuitable.

Depending on what kind of power supply you have, it could be the supply itself, or just a worn out or otherwise unsuitable cable.

(Tip: If you see the rainbow square in the top corner of your screen at any time, it means the Pi is not getting enough power.)

**Logs**:

Look for anything out of the ordinary on bootup.  `dmesg` or as mentioned by @Milliways, `systemd-analyze critical-chain` (I didn't know about this one)